# Finding the maximum displacement of a mass from its initial position using algebraic/trigonometric methods

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

A minimum of calculus is used. The velocity of the bob is

$$v(t)= x'(t)= 3\sin{t}+4\cos{t}$$

At $t=0$, the mass is $1$ unit from the initial position.

I set the derivative equal to zero to find the max displacement, but I got a negative answer ($t\approx-0.927$). $t$ has to be greater than zero, but I don't know how to find the appropriate answer given the one I have.

Comment: It asks you to find the maximum DISPLACEMENT, which is the integral of $v(t)$. So you need to find the integral first.

Comment: That makes sense, and maybe I explained it wrong but those were the instructions I followed on the problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are the instructions of the problem. I think the displacement can be found by integral, then set the derivative of the displacement to 0 to obtain the maximum. On the other hand, the derivative of the displacement is the velocity itself.

So setting the velocity to 0 would give you the time when the displacement is maximum.

$$3\sin{t}+4\cos{t}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{3}{5}\sin{t}+\frac{4}{5}\cos{t}=0\\
\sin{(t+\arccos{(3/5)})}=0$$

So $t=\pi-\arccos{(3/5)}$. Notice that it is periodic, so using $\pi-$ or $2\pi-$ are both OK.

Plugging this $t$ into your displacement function would give you the maximum.

An alternative way:

The displacement function is $-3\cos{t}+4\sin{t}+4$ by integral.

Using the same argument as above this gives you

$$5(-\frac{3}{5}\cos{t}+\frac{4}{5}\sin{t})+4$$

The quantity in parenthesis is $\sin{(t+\theta)}$ for some $\theta$. Its maximum must be $1$. So the maximum of the displacement must be $9$.

Comment: The maximum displacement from the *equilibrium position* is $5$, not $9$.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating and noting initial condition we have $x(t)=-3\cos(t)+4 \sin (t)+4$. This can be written as $x(t)=5\cos(t-(\pi-\arctan(\frac{4}{3}))+4$.

Proof:

Consider the vector $\vec v=<-3,4>$ and the unit vector $\vec w=<cos (\theta), \sin (\theta)>$.

$$\vec v \cdot \vec w=|\vec v||\vec w| \cos( \text{angle, between, them})$$

$$=(\sqrt{3^2+4^2})(1) \cos ((\pi-\arctan(\frac{4}{3}))-\theta)$$

$$=(\sqrt{3^2+4^2})(1) \cos (\theta-(\pi-\arctan(\frac{4}{3})))$$

Answer (score 0):

$v(t) = 3\sin(t) + 4\cos(t)$. Integrating gives:

$s(t) = -3\cos(t) + 4\sin(t) + C = 5\sin(t-0.6435...) + C$ by the R addition formulae.

Let the starting position be $S$ and the equilibrium position be $O$.

Now regardless of what $C$ is, the maximum displacement from $O$ is $5$ units. The times that the maximum displacement occurs are when $t-0.6435... = \pi/2 + 2k\pi, k\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}$

Answer (score 0):

Short hand $(s,c,tn)= \sin t, \cos t ,\tan t $

Velocity $v(t)= 3s +4c$

For maximum displacement the above velocity vanishes.

$$ 3s+4c=0, \;tn= \dfrac{4}{-3} = \dfrac{-4}{3}$$

For negative tan value, the radius vector tip for $t$ should be either in second (case A) or fourth ( Case B) quadrants.

*case A*
$$ s= \dfrac{4}{5};\;c= \dfrac{-3}{5} \tag 1 $$

*case B*
$$ s= \dfrac{-4}{5};\;c= \dfrac{3}{5} \tag 2 $$

Integrate the given velocity

$$x(t)= -3c+4s+C_1 \tag3 $$

BC $ t=0, x=1; \to C_1=4 \to x(t)= 4-3c+4s \;\tag4 $

Plug case A into (4)

$$ x_{max}= \dfrac{25}{5} + 4 =9 $$

Plug case B into (4)

$$ x_{min}= \dfrac{-25}{5}+4 = -1 $$

Position, velocity $ x(t),x'(t)$ are graphed at respective instants of time:

[image]